# How can i get the closest distance between a tuple and a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, euclidean-distance

I want to find the tuple inside a list that is closest to my given tuple.

i have a list of coordinates and a point and i need to find the item in the list that is closest to my point.

something like this:

```py
cords =  [(455, 12), (188, 90), (74, 366), (10,10)]
point = (18, 448)

for c in cords:
    dst = distance.euclidean(cords[c], point)
```

`Output = closest distance`

I tried using `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` but this gives the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: In the first iteration `c` is the tuple `(455, 12)`-. What do you expect `cords[(455, 12)]` to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python `min` allows to specify a single-argument function that returns a value (the "`key`") and it will return the element that minimizes it.

```
min(cords, key=lambda c : distance.euclidean(c, point))
```

Comment: This will give the point with the minimum distance, to get the minimum distance you'll have to calculate it again.

Comment: OP: "I want to find **the tuple** inside a list that is closest to my given tuple"

Comment: Then I was tricked by `Output = closest distance` in the question.

Answer (score 4):

`c` is the tuple in the list of coords, it's not the index, so use it instead of `cords[c]`, you can also use `min` with a generator expression to get what you want:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

cords =  [(455, 12), (188, 90), (74, 366), (10, 10)]
point = (18, 448)

closest_dst = min(euclidean(c, point) for c in cords)
print(closest_dst)
```

Output:

```
99.29753269845128
```

Comment: no need for generators in min if you use the `key` argument ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `for c in range(len(cords))`. As you are, you are taking elements of list into `c`, not indexes.

Comment: `len(cords)` returns an integer, which is not iterable (so this code raises an error...)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing it the object c as an index. You could do it using enumerate if you want to use the index or just do it the pythonic way:

```
cords =  [(455, 12), (188, 90), (74, 366), (10,10)]
point = (18, 448)

for c in cords:
    dst = distance.euclidean(c, point)
```

You should save the distances and find the minimum as well.